# How to push items into an angular $scope.array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I'm doing something wrong yet I cannot see what (this is probably due to my low AngularJS skills).
I have a simple ng-repeat in my HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="fot in fotografia"><img src="{{fot.path}}"></li>
</ul>
```

and here is my app.js:

```
myApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    // fotografia = []; is here only because I get an error otherwise,
    // which means my later for loop can't access the $scope.fotografia

    fotografia = [];
    $scope.fotografia = [
        {path:'img/fotografia/fot_1.jpg'},
        {path:'img/fotografia/fot_2.jpg'}
    ];

    // I want to add more images with this:
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        fotografia.push({
            path: 'img/fotografia/fot_'+[i]+'.jpg'
        });
    }
});
```

Ng-repeat works fine with the 2 images I already have in my array (fot_1.jpg, fot_2.jpg). The loop is the the problem. How do I go about pushing more items into my array?

Comment: The only way this would work is if made both `fotografia` and `$scope.fotografia` reference the same array, ie `fotografia = $scope.fotografia = []`, the way you have it now they reference two different arrays

Comment: you just forgot use $scope. the view is binded to $scope variables not private variables.

Comment: Moreover, even if this has no impact in your current code, but JSON standard defines that String shall be delimited by double quotes ". Your image shall be  {path:"img/fotografia/fot_1.jpg"}. To solve your issue, replace fotografia by $scope.fotografia into your controller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just push them onto the array in the scope. angular will then update the view.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    $scope.fotografia.push({
        path: 'img/fotografia/fot_'+[i]+'.jpg'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fotografia` is a property of the `$scope` object, so you would do something like:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  $scope.fotografia.push({
    path: 'img/fotografia/fot_'+[i]+'.jpg'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular will update the view when everything in scope is changed or you use
`$scope.digest()`.
so just push items into the array in scope,remove the 
`fotografia = [];`
because you don't need it.
just like this:

```

```
myApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.fotografia = [
        {path:'img/fotografia/fot_1.jpg'},
        {path:'img/fotografia/fot_2.jpg'}
    ];
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        $scope.fotografia.push({
            path: 'img/fotografia/fot_'+[i]+'.jpg'
        });
    }
});
```

```